# Git rebasing multiple branches

Tags: git

I have 3 branches: main branch A, branch B that is branched from A at some point, and branch C that is branched from B.
On each branch there is new commits, branch B needs to have code from A as base, branch C needs to be on top of B.
This is my current situation:

```
 | | |
 | | /
 | | C
 |/B
 |
 A
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
    |
    /
   | C
   | 
   |
  /B
 |
 |
 |
 |
 A
```

So first I did:

```
B: git pull --rebase origin B
git checkout C
git rebase B
```

so the branch C is on top of B.

Then I did same for branch A:

```
A: git pull --rebase origin A
git checkout B
git rebase A
```

Then I switched to branch C, and I noticed that I dont have changes from A (I thought that if C is on top of B, and B is on top of A, it means C has changes from A), or maybe I should have done it in reverse order.

Now I have diverged branch B (probably should force push to remote).

Can I `git rebase B` again on C branch? Is there posibility I lose something? Note that all branches are pushed to remote.

Answer (score 0):

`--onto` option is what you are looking for.

```
git checkout b
git rebase --onto a b^
git checkout c
git rebase --onto b c^
```

Answer (score 0):

You should've started by rebasing B and then C. What should've been done is the following:

```
# STEP 1
A: git pull --rebase origin A
git checkout B
git rebase A

# STEP 2
B: git pull --rebase origin B
git checkout C
git rebase B
```

And it's pretty obvious if you think about it.

Now to fix that, we know that A is good and B is good too. Only C needs to move up.

```
git checkout C
git rebase --onto B A C
```

Hope that helps